# Splitting strings with perl

Tags: string, perl, split

I have a large chunk of text that will come through. I want to split the chunk so it is no longer than 50 characters. I can do that part, but what I really need is that it doesnt split in the middle of a word but on a blank. For instance, if I have the phrase:
 Hello world? I want to split this string!

Lets say for example on that string I want to split it so it is no longer than 10 characters each segment, but I dont want to split a word. Is there an easy method to do that?

Comment: This is one of those problems that's easy to solve in C and more difficult in Perl unless you can find a nice library (like Text::Wrap below).  If you want a C solution, say so and I can provide.

Comment: @Gene, Why, is there an existing C library? If you're starting from scratch, it would still be easier with Perl because of its regex engine.

Comment: I disagree.  Chopping prefixes from a string, especially this kind of prefix with a length criterion, is awkward with a regex. And it's slow because you end up copying the string (which in this case is large). On the other hand, it's very simple with a C program processing and generating output character-by-character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Text::Wrap qw( wrap );

sub my_wrap {
    local $Text::Wrap::columns = 10;
    return wrap('', '', @_);
}

say my_wrap("Hello, World!");
```

[Text::Wrap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aWrap)

Comment: +1 The command line utility `fold` also comes to mind: `fold -s -w 10`

Comment: First is there a way to make it no more than 10 characters so if it is splitting on a word it chooses the blank before 10? Like with this to have it say "Hello," "World" and so on through the whole string? I just chose 10 to work with smaller numbers.

Comment: @steve I may not need to do this on every string. The strings are being pulled from a site and read into email. Sometimes the strings are smaller than 50 and sometimes they are larger. If they are larger I want to cut them

Comment: @shinjuo, What makes you think it doesn't?!

Comment: @ikegami sorry I read your code wrong. I was thinking you meant the output was "Hello World". I see what you are saying now. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you aren't familiar with Perl 5.10's [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html)???